# Why can't Android Studio on my mac detect my Nexus 6 for the "Choose Device" list?

Tags: android-studio

I enabled USB debugging under Developer Options in my Nexus 6 and connected it to my mac via a USB cable.

I open Android Studio to run my app to find that the Nexus 6 is not listed in the Choose Devices list. The phone is on and running. I tried restarting it.

Why isn't the Nexus 6 listed? [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) notes that "it should just work" for macs.

Comment: i have the same problem here - did you download all the SDKs?

Comment: I switched to another cable and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the issue is with USB cable. Try to use genuine USB cable. also try to create new project before experimenting.